# What is an efficient way to compare StringBuilder objects

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Well I have two StringBuilder objects, I need to compare them in Java.
One way I know I can do is

```
sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString());
```

but that means I am creating two String objects, is there any better way to compare StringBuilder objects. Probably something where you do not need to create additional objects?

Comment: I'm surprised that `StringBuilder` doesn't declare its own `equals` method.

Comment: what you are doing is the best way to do this, barring exceeding large `String` objects.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As you apparently already know, `StringBuilder` inherits `equals()` from `java.lang.Object`, and as such `StringBuilder.equals()` returns true only when passed the same object as an argument. It does **not** compare the contents of two `StringBuilder`s!

If you look at the source, you'll conclude that the most efficient comparison (that didn't involve creating any new objects) would be to compare `.length()` return values, and then if they're the same, compare the return values of `charAt(i)` for each character.

Comment: FYI, `charAt(i)` is a thin veneer (with parameter bounds checking) over `value[i]`, where `value` is the `char[]` holding the current String, so yeah - this is the fastest way. And may I add, it is retarded that in 2012 we all need to implement this instead of it being inside the `StringBuilder` class with a tight loop impl. Is there not an apache commons static method that does this?

Comment: @Bohemian, I am sure there is something in Apache Commons, but I am always loath to ask people to pull that package in for just one method like this.

Comment: I don't hold with that, because *the best code is someone else's code*, so if there's a proxy standard library out there (even if a little lame), I always recommend using it. Also, once they get a taste for commons methods, they will find more uses for them... `less code == good`.

Comment: If only stringbuilder allowed us to get a reference of the underlying char[] buffer that resides in AbstractStringBuilder so we could then use Arrays.equals(char[], char[]) on it :P

Comment: Strange there is no method to compare the content of stringBuilder objects

Answer (score 27):

Since Java 11, `StringBuilder` implements `Comparable`, so you can use a `compareTo` method for the equality test:

```
System.out.println(sb1.compareTo(sb2) == 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two StringBuilder objects are never equal. Use .toString() to get the string representation for both the objects and then use .equals() to compare the objects. This way equals() method from the String class gets invoked that compares the string value of the objects instead of comparing the memory location.

```
StringBuilder a= new StringBuilder("HELLO JAVA");
StringBuilder b= new StringBuilder("HELLO JAVA");
if (a.toString().equals(b.toString())){
System.out.println("Objects are equal");
}
```

Comment: But that is not efficient as you create a new String instance is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without new allocations would be to compare first at length, and if it differs, then char by char. This is more efficient and faster than performing a compare via a toString() on the StringBuilder call, which would allocate a new string.

The next snipped assumes both parameters aren't null neither the same object instance:

```
public boolean compare(final StringBuilder left, final StringBuilder right) {
    final int length = left.length();

    if (length != right.length())
        return false;

    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        if (left.charAt(index) != right.charAt(index))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```