# StringBuilder .equals Java

Tags: java

```
class strb
{

    static public void main(String...string)
    {
         StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Test");
         StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("Test");

         System.out.println(s1); // output: Test
         System.out.println(s2); // Test
         System.out.println(s1==s2); // false
         System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //Line 1 output: false
         System.out.println(s1.toString()==s2.toString()); //Line 2 output: false
    }

}
```

Just have a quick question on .equals.

Regardless of the object content, does `.equals` return true only if both the object references point to the same object ?

---

**EDIT** : Now I understand the part about the `.equals` but why does Line 2 not return `true` ?

**EDIT** : I believe `==` looks at the reference variable's address and so s1 and s2 cannot be equal.correct me if my assumption is not right

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112602/why-does-stringbuffer-stringbuilder-not-override-equals-or-hashcode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007387/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-compare-stringbuilder-objects

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, `StringBuilder` does *not* override `Object`'s `.equals()` function, which means the two object references are not the same and the result is `false`.

For `StringBuilder`, you could use `s1.toString().equals(s2.toString())`

For your edit, you're calling the `==` operator on two different String objects. The `==` operator will return false because the objects are different. To compare Strings, you need to use `String.equals()` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`

It's the same problem you were having earlier.

Comment: do you know why StringBuilder does not override equals() method.It seems strange.

Comment: Essentially, if I had to guess, if you have two StringBuilders, you're more likely to test if they're the same StringBuilder that's been building your string rather than two different builders with the same string. I can't think of many cases where two different instantiated StringBuilders would be building the same thing.

Comment: Regarding your 1st sentence, I thought "==" tested references, and ".equals()" tested object values?

Comment: I think StringBuilder() cant compare object values just this!!

Answer (score 4):

The `StringBuilder` class does not provide an overriden `equals()` method. As such, when that method is called on an instance of `StringBuilder`, the `Object` class implementation of the method is executed, since `StringBuilder extends Object`.

The source code for that is

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Which simply compares reference equality.

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation of `.equals` for the `Object` class is as you mentioned.

Other classes can override this behavior.  `StringBuilder` is not one of them.

String is one of them, which overrides it to ensure that the String representations of both objects result in the same sequence of characters.  [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Refer to the documentation for the specific object in question.

Answer (score 2):

for your first answer check @abmitchell 's Answer

**And for your Edit:**

In Java, String is an object and we can't compare objects for value equality by using `==`

`==` is used for comparing primitives values or object references.

To compare Object values we use `equals()` in Java

Answer (score 2):

Check the contract of `equals` method:

it must be consistent (if the objects are not modified, then it must keep returning the same value).

That's why StringBuilder does not override it regardless of its content.

Let's take example above.

```
     StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Test");
     StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("Test");
```

Maybe, to you it is expected that `s1.equals(s2)` returns `true` due to current run time values.

But what about if you change add line:

```
    s1.append("abc");
```

Then s1 and s2 will have different string contents and `s1.equals(s2)` is expected to be `false`. But it is in contradiction with consistency.

Comment: *"Check the contract of equals method"* excellent explanation of why StringBuilder does not implement `.equals()`. Great answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this remains a violation of least astonishment.  Take your interpretation of the charter: "if the objects are not modified".  Well the objects _are_ modified.  The goal of the equals() method is an evaluation of the functional equivalence of two objects.  "Consistency", by your assessment, would never be violated by any object because no object, mutable or otherwise, would fall into that category.  The moment mutation happens to an object (e.g. `.append()`), the contract of the equals() _should always_ reflect a contents change.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` not override the equals function of `Object` class.but string override the `equals` method.
the function of `Object` is this

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
    }
```

you could write your code like this.

```
System.out.println(s1.toString() == s2.toString());
System.out.println(s1.toString().equals(s2.toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` class doesn't have the implementation of `equals()` method like one in the `String` class.

So it executes default Object class functionality, which again checks only for address equivalency, which is not same in this case. so it prints false.

**Note 1**: You can use `==` operator on objects also, but it simply checks if the address of both the objects are same or not.

**Note 2**: `==` operator plays good role in comparing two String objects created in string constant pool, to find out if it is really creating a new object in string constant pool or not.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `StringBuilder` does not override `equals`. However, it does implement `Comparable` (since Java 11). Therefore, you can check `s1.compareTo(s2) == 0` to find out if the string representations are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with both of the above responses, but I'm worth noting to actually compare contents you can do:

```
System.out.println(s1.toString().equals(s2.toString())); //Line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since StringBuilder does not have a **equals** method, it is best to first change the StringBuilder to String and then check equality.
Eg - `sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString())`.

Note: The **==** operator or `sb1 == sb2` will never work here because the two StringBuilder(s) are completely different objects.