# StringBuilder Equals in c# and Java

Tags: java, c#, stringbuilder

I have just come across this [StringBuilder .equals Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565701/stringbuilder-equals-java), where java StringBuilder does not have Equals() implementation. However, in c# I observed there is an Equals() implementation available for `StringBuilder` class. I would particularly want to know how this is handled in C# and why not in Java.

Comment: Different frameworks take different approaches - to find out why they were designed that way, you'd probably need to ask the teams that designed them. Equality of mutable types can be useful, but it can also be unhelpful.

Comment: In java, StringBuilder.toString() has equals() to compare the string value

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder.equals()` actually exists, but it does not compare the Strings. From a Java perspective, this is the correct approach. `StringBuilder`s mutate, that's their purpose, which makes two different `StringBuilder` objects un-equal by definition. Most newer Java APIs follow the approach that `equal()` is implemented for immutable or final classes, although there are exceptions. Mutable classes, on the other hand, usually simply inherit `Object.equals()` which relies on object-identity.

There are at least two reasons behind this. One is the ability to properly use objects in hash-based data structures, i.e. as value in a `HashSet` or a key in a `HashMap`. Although this depends on `Object.hashCode()`, it affects `Object.equals()` because the `hashCode` should be stable over an object's life time if it is to be used as an entry in a hash-based datastructure, and `equals()` is defined to be consistent with `hashCode()`.

The other is that `Object.equals()` is defined to be symmetrical, and carelessly overriding `Object.equals()` can break that symmetry.

All in all, in Java, `Object.equals()` shouldn't be understood as value-equality but as equality according to the nature of the instances.