# Does the .equals() method work with StringBuilders?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to make a program that tests whether a user entered string is a palindrome or not.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class palindrome{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  System.out.println("Enter text");
  String inputstr = input.nextLine();
  sb.append(inputstr);
  if((sb).equals(sb.reverse())){
    System.out.println("Palindrome");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
    }
    }
}
```

There are no compile time errors, however no matter what I enter, the output is palindrome. Is there some sort of incompatibility between .equals() and StringBuilder? If so, is there any workaround?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18565731/1793718

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals`, so you should use `String`'s `equals` instead.

```
if(sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString()))
```

P.S even if it did override `equals`, your test would always return true, since you are comparing a `StringBuilder` instance to itself (`reverse` doesn't return a new `StringBuilder` instance).

Comment: Actually, `StringBuilder` operates in-place.  The returned `StringBuilder` is the same object.

Comment: Thanks, converting it to a string solved the problem, and I will keep the P.S. in mind.