# StringBuilder equals() method is not working as expected

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am solving the 125. Valid Palindrome problem in leetcode. For testcase

> A man, a plan, a canal: Panama

with below code, it is returning false:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char curr = s.charAt(i);
            if ((curr <= 57 && curr >= 48) || (curr >= 97 && curr <= 122) || (curr <= 90 && curr >= 65)) {
                curr = Character.toLowerCase(curr);
                s1.append(curr);
            }
        }
        s2.append(s1);
        s2.reverse();
        if (s2.equals(s1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it valid palindrome?

Comment: Off-topic:  `if (foo.equals(bar)) { return true; } return false;` is equivalent to `return foo.equals(bar);`

Comment: For reference, LeetCode 125 page is https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/

Comment: When a method does not work as expected, it's a good idea to check the API. The [StringBuilder API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) has this note: *"API Note:
StringBuilder implements Comparable but does not override equals. Thus, the natural ordering of StringBuilder is inconsistent with equals. "* (in part).

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565701/stringbuilder-equals-java

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is the problem:

```
if(s2.equals(s1)) {
    return true;
}
```

What you are doing here is comparing two `StringBuilder` objects, and they are obviously always different. What you should to instead is to compare the `String`s that are build using those builders. To get the string from the builder you need to use `toString` method. So, your code should look like that:

```
if(s2.toString().equals(s1.toString())) {
    return true;
}
```

I've tested your code with this change and it works correctly now.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```java
if(s2.equals(s1)) {
      return true;
}
```

to

```java
if (s2.compareTo(s1) == 0) {
      return true;
 }
```

Comment: Note: this solution will work only for Java 11+, before that `StringBuilder` hadn't implemented the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* simplify the whole process by using a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) passed to the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_replaceall.htm) method, for example:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        String regEx = "\\p{Punct}|\\s+";
        return s.replaceAll(regEx, "").equalsIgnoreCase(
                new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString().replaceAll(regEx, ""));
    }
}
```

**What does the used Regular Expression mean?**

- `\\p{Punct}` All punctuation and special characters;
- `|` OR;
- `\\s+` Any white-space character (equivalent to:  `\r` (Carraige
  Return),  `\n` (Newline or Linefeed), `\t` (Tab), `\f` (Formfeed),
  etc) one or unlimited times.

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent the problem of missing `StringBuilder.equals` by not using it. Instead, you can directly compare characters of the filtered string:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    var filtered = s.codePoints()
            .filter(Character::isLetterOrDigit)
            .map(Character::toLowerCase)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);
    var length = filtered.length();
    return IntStream.range(0, length / 2)
            .allMatch(i -> filtered.codePointAt(i) == filtered.codePointAt(length - 1 - i));
}
```